# Python KeyError in a dictionary containing a list

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

Can anyone tell my why that function gives me a KeyError?

```
def countLinks(url):
    urlCounter = {"dummy":[0,0]}
    urlList = getLinks(url)
    for x in urlList:
        if x in urlCounter:
            urlCounter[x][1] += 1
        else:
            urlCounter[x][1] = 1
    return urlCounter
```

getLinks just returns a list with HTML links in it.

The reason for the second value is that i need to keep track if this URL has been crawled.

BTW Python 3.0 used.

Many thx in advance

Comment: `if x (not) in urlCounter:` and `urlCounter[x][1] = 1` you are accessing a key when you know it is not in the dict. no wonder there is a keyerror.

Comment: damn, without the list as value it worked and just added that key and value. Thx for the tip I think I may know a solution :-)

Comment: def countLinks(url):
    urlCounter = {"dummy":[0,0]}
    urlList = getLinks(url)
    for x in urlList:
        if x in urlCounter:
            urlCounter[x][0] += 1
        else:
            urlCounter[x] = [1,0]
    return urlCounter

Comment: @sadoMasupilami That's because `dict[x] = y` will create the entry in the dict. In your example you are setting a value in a list but to access that value you need to access the list via key. A key that isn't there.

Comment: else:
            urlCounter[x] = [1,0]

Comment: that did the trick, so many THX to you for helping me!

Comment: PLZ help me to improve my questions, why was this one voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in urlList:
        if x in urlCounter:
            urlCounter[x][1] += 1
        else:
            urlCounter[x][1] = 1  # you need to create the dict entry here too.
```

In this situation when checking if a dict has a key and creating it if it's not there it's important to remember to create it.

```
for x in urlList:
        if x in urlCounter:
            urlCounter[x][1] += 1
        else:
            urlCounter[x] = [0,1]
```

Comment: THX that is exactly what i was missing! hail stack overflow :-)

Comment: Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or at least a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be much more idiomatic Python.

Comment: I'm just a beginner but I will have a look into this!

Comment: @sadoMasupilami I strongly suggest you do - they were made for exactly this purpose. `defaultdict` initializes a key with a default value if you insert one that isn't in there yet, and `Counter` is an even more specialized `defaultdict` made for... counting things.